# unattended update PCs via foreman

Tags: puppet, foreman, linuxmint

I have recently became responsible for about 50 workstations running Mint Linux 17. The PCs are used for very basic data entry and only require a working browser. Although i'm told the PCs basically "run themselves" it would be nice to have some sort of monitoring system to check in. Over the slow times of the holidays I installed Foreman and have it working with all the workstations but I am intrigue by the software and would like to take it to that next step.

One thing I would like to do is deploy a cron job to auto update the PCs. I know this is generally not a good idea but being used by a number of different employees even just the security updates will make me sleep better at night. Since they already have Mint Linux running I'm hoping I don't have to configure a cron job on each PC individually and can start getting comfortable with the foreman setup.

There is a tutorial on the Mint Linux site explaining how to enable unattended updates (http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1217) but is this something I can deploy from foreman?

Thanks,

Comment: Look into http://www.katello.org/, it might help you.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add I have Foreman running on Debian. Katello doesn't look to support Debian.

Comment: Ah sorry, I forget about the yum-only base of Katello, namely Pulp.

Answer (score 0):

What was said, the good strategy would be to replicate yum repositories onto a local mirror in some managable way so you can control *what* goes there and filter out only updates you are interested in. Then configure your PCs to auto upgrade every night or similar.

For this the best software out there is *Pulp* (www.pulpproject.org). There is a plugin into Foreman that works with Pulp called *Katello*. It allows fine grained control with content paths (promotions) within containers (environments). It is a bit complex tool, you can maybe start with pure Pulp with Foreman too. It will work just fine.